# запрет на выключение экрана

Tags: flutter, dart

Если к экрану не прикосаться, то через некоторое время он выключается (время выставлено в настройках). В Android Kotlin это делается так в разметке

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

в коде

```
activity_main.keepScreenOn = true
```

Как сделать во Flutter, что бы не выключался? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть пара плагинов способных решить вашу проблему:

Для Android предварительно следует добавить разрешение в манифест

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

1. [wakelock](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock):

```dart
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';

// Запретить экрану отключаться:
Wakelock.enable(); // или Wakelock.toggle(on: true);

// Разрешить экрану отключаться:
Wakelock.disable(); // или Wakelock.toggle(on: false);
```

2. [screen](https://pub.dev/packages/screen):

```
import 'package:screen/screen.dart';

// Предотвращение перехода экрана в спящий режим:
Screen.keepOn(true);
```

Comment: Уважаемый Serge Shkurko, большое Вам спасибо!